# Is scholarship tax free next to a salary?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, germany, scholarship

Last year I received a six months research scholarship from DAAD within a collaboration with a Germany university. The total grant was around 21550 Euros. At the same time I was receiving my monthly wage from the USA.

A scholarship in [Germany is tax free](https://www.euraxess.de/germany/informationen-beratung/steuern/tax-exemption-fellowships) as well as in the [USA](https://taxdepartment.gwu.edu/taxation-scholarships-fellowships-stipends-0#:%7E:text=A%20scholarship%2Ffellowship%20payment%20received,supplies%2C%20and%20equipment%20required%20of), however, I am bit concerned because at the same time I had my salary.
In this case is the scholarship tax free? Do I have to submit a tax declaration in Germany and pay the tax of [1907 Euros](https://visualsm.art/gross-net-salary-calculator/)
there, as my salary is taxed in the USA, and apply for "Foreign Earned Income Exclusion" in the USA? Or I just file my tax clearance in the USA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scholarship is not tax free in the US. The webpage you linked to says so right there:

> A scholarship/fellowship payment received by a candidate for a degree is generally not taxable income to the student **if it is used for "qualified expenses."**. ... A scholarship/fellowship used for expenses other than qualified expenses is taxable income.

There are strings attached and you have to retain receipts to be able to prove that you complied with all the requirements if and when you're audited.

Regarding Germany, you're likely covered by [the tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/germany-tax-treaty-documents) to only be taxed in the US, but a licensed professional should confirm this. You've not provided enough details here to know for sure.

Comment: What details can I provide? Shall I contact to licensed professional in the USA or in Germany?

Comment: @KicsiMano I'd say someone who's proficient in both, I'm sure there are firms in Germany doing taxes for US expats. Details depend on specific time ranges, your status in Germany, whatever local laws are, etc